# Relationship between disorder of a permutation and order of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any relationship between disorder of a permutation and order of a permutation?

Comment: You might want to define what the "disorder of a permutation" is.

Answer (score 1):

Emeric Deutsch said at [OEIS A008302](http://oeis.org/A008302)

> The disorder of a permutation $p$ of
>   $(1,2,\ldots ,n)$ is defined in the
>   following manner. We scan $p$ from left
>   to right as often as necessary until
>   all its elements are removed in
>   increasing order, scoring one point
>   for each occasion on which an element
>   is passed over and not removed. The
>   disorder of $p$ is the number of points
>   scored by the end of the scanning and
>   removal process. For example, the
>   disorder of $(3,5,2,1,4)$ is $8$, since on
>   the first scan, $3$, $5$, $2$ and $4$ are passed
>   over, on the second, $3$, $5$ and $4$ and on
>   the third scan, $5$ is once again not
>   removed.

That suggests that the disorder is calculated from the order. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: How does this suggest the disorder is calculated from the order?

Comment: This is "abbreviated 2-line notation", I think: that is, "(3,5,2,1,4)" means the permutation that sends 1 to 3, 2 to 5, 3 to 2, 4 to 1, and 5 to 4. Otherwise, if this were "cycle notation", the disorder would depend on the representation: (1,4,3,5,2) is the same cycle permutation as (3,5,2,1,4), but the disorder would be 5. Just thought it might be worth mentioning...

Comment: I think the disorder of $p=(3,5,2,1,4)$ is $6$, not $8$. We count $(i,j)$ such that $i\lt j$ but $p(i)\gt p(j)$. E.g., $1\lt 3$ but $p(1)=3\gt2=p(3)$ so we count $(1,3)$. We count $(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4)$, that's $6$. I doubt there's any simple relation between disorder of $p$ and its order as an element of $S_n$.

Comment: Deutsch published a Monthly problem on this topic.  Here's the JSTOR link:

http://www.jstor.org/stable/4145088

Answer (score 1):

I've defined the disorder in my comment on Henry's answer. (EDIT: this is the way it is defined in Section 2.13 of Chris Cooper's [notes](https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/Cooper/Groups/CHAP02%20Permutations.pdf).) If the disorder is zero then $p$ is the identity, order $1$. If the disorder is $1$ then $p$ is a transposition, in fact, a transposition of the form $(a\quad a+1)$, so of order $2$. But if the disorder is $2$ then $p$ could be $(a\quad a+1)(b\quad b+1)$ of order $2$ or $(a\quad a+1\quad a+2)$ of order $3$. The disorder can be high even if the order is $2$ (use $(1\quad n)$), and fairly low even if the order is high (e.g. $(1\quad2)(3\quad4\quad5)(6\quad7\quad8\quad9\quad10)$ has disorder $7$ and order $30$). In short, I don't think you can say very much about either number based solely on knowledge of the other.